# Two elements `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` are not in the same line

Tags: css

I have this [site](http://www.ziiweb.com). As you can see, the menu bar is below the social networks buttons. Since the container div of social network buttons is set as `display: inline-block` and the navbar is set as `display: inline`, I expected both elements were in the same line like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3YNb5/1/), but no.. why?

```
<header class="tab-content cabecera">
      <a class="logo pull-left" href="/">
        <img src="images/logo1.png" width="250px" alt="ziiweb"/>
      </a>
      <div class="social">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/!!!" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        <g:plusone align="middle"></g:plusone>
      </div>
      <nav style="display: inline">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Qué ofrecemos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: @AndréDion I replied your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.social` is set to `display: block;`

If you want both your `<nav>` and `.social` elements to appear next to one another, set them both to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Thanks, it works, but I can not understand why it doesn't work with just `inline`, since `inline` doesn't generate breakpoints as `inline-block`..Any documentation or concept that am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "inline doesn't generate breakpoints"? For reading material, [here's some documentation for the `display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and [some use cases](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use `float:left;` to make whole nav element to be in same line.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div and keep both `.social` and `nav` in it. Use `display: inline-block;` in that
Also use `float: left;` in `.social`

```
<div class="outer" style="display: inline-block; width: 700px;">
 <div class="social" style="float: left;">...</div>
 <nav>...</nav>
</div>
```

Other way is what **André Dion** answered.

Answer (score 0):

I `.social` is set to `display: inline-block;` then set `nav` to `display: inline-block;` too.

Answer (score 0):

Both elements nav and  should have "vertical-align:top;", in default is vertical centred.